# How to avoid out-of-memory error when creating large arrays from PySpark and Parquet for data analysis?

Tags: memory-management, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, parquet

We have a somewhat unusual requirement that we're experimenting with. We have a parquet table with ~320 GB of frequency pixel values in arrays - the data is from a 3-dimensional spectral line image cube (A FITs source file).

```
+--------------------+------------+-------+
|            col_name|   data_type|comment|
+--------------------+------------+-------+
|           spi_index|         int|   null|
|           spi_image|array<float>|   null|
|        spi_filename|      string|   null|
|            spi_band|         int|   null|
|# Partition Infor...|            |       |
|          # col_name|   data_type|comment|
|        spi_filename|      string|   null|
|            spi_band|         int|   null|
+--------------------+------------+-------+
```

There is a legacy source finding algorithm written in C that is used to analyse the original data source files, but it's restrained to the physical memory available on one machine. We're running a CDH Express cluster, 3 management nodes (8 cores, 32 GB ram) 10 worker nodes (16 cores, 64 GB ram) and a gateway node running Jupyterhub (8 cores, 32 GB of ram). We've modified the original C program into a shared object, and distributed it across the cluster. We've incorporated the C shared object into a partitioner class so we can run multiple partitions in multiple executors across the cluster. We have this up and running using pyspark.

The problem that we're experiencing is that we optimally need an input pixel array of a minimum of about 15GB and we seem to be hitting a wall at creating arrays of around 7.3 GB, and we're unsure of why this is.

YARN maximum allocation setting.

```
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 40GB
```

Spark configuration settings

```
--executor-memory 18g \
--num-executors 29 \
--driver-memory 18g \
--executor-cores 5 \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead='22g' \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead='22g' \
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize='24g' \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=20G -XX:+UseCompressedOops" \
```

Summary of partitioner class

```
class Partitioner:
def __init__(self):
    self.callPerDriverSetup
    
def callPerDriverSetup(self):
    pass

def callPerPartitionSetup(self):
    sys.path.append('sofia')
    #import example
    
    import sofia
    import myLib
    
    import faulthandler
    import time as tm
    from time import time, clock, process_time, sleep 

     
    self.sofia=sofia
    self.myLib=myLib
    #self.example=example
    self.parameterFile=SparkFiles.get('sofia.par')
    
def doProcess(self, element):
    ###  here's the call to the C library for each row of the dataframe partition
    ### In here we have to transform the flattened array data to the format SoFiA
    ### requires, as well as the
    
    ra=np.array(element.right_ascension, dtype='<f4')
    dec=np.array(element.declination, dtype='<f4')
    frequencies=np.array(element.frequency, dtype='<f4')
    Pixels=np.array(element.pixels, dtype='<f4')
    
    
    dataPtr= Pixels.ravel()
            
    #
    # create the dictionary of the original header
    #
    hdrKey = np.array(element.keys, dtype='U')
    hdrValue = np.array(element.values, dtype='U')
    hdrDict = dict(zip(hdrKey,hdrValue))
    
    newHdr=self.myLib.CreateHeader(hdrDict)
    
    # Get the crpix adjustment values for the new header
    crpix1,crpix2,crpix3,crpix4=self.myLib.GetHeaderUpdates(newHdr,\
                                      element.raHeaderIndex, \
                                      element.decHeaderIndex, \
                                      element.freqHeaderIndex)
    # Get the new axis values
    naxis1 = len(ra)
    naxis2 = len(dec)
    naxis4 = len(frequencies)
    
    newHdr['CRPIX1']=float(crpix1)
    newHdr['CRPIX2']=float(crpix2)
    newHdr['CRPIX3']=float(crpix3)
    newHdr['CRPIX4']=float(crpix4)
    
    newHdr['NAXIS1']=float(naxis1)
    newHdr['NAXIS2']=float(naxis2)
    newHdr['NAXIS4']=float(naxis4)
    
    newHdr.pop("END",None)
    
    hdrstr,hdrsize = self.myLib.dict2FITSstr(newHdr)
    
    path_to_par = self.parameterFile
    parsize = len(path_to_par)
    # pass off to sofia C library
    try:
        # This is the call to the shared object
        ret = self.sofia.sofia_mainline(dataPtr,hdrstr,hdrsize,path_to_par,parsize)
        returnCode= ret[0]
        sofiaMsg="Call to sofia has worked!"
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Caught general exception\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught general exception"
        returnCode=1
        #sys.exit()
    except StopIteration:
        print("Caught Null pointer\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught Null pointer"
        returnCode=2
        #sys.exit()
    except MemoryError:
        print("Caught ALLOC error\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught ALLOC error"
        returnCode=3
        #sys.exit()
    except IndexError:
        print("Caught index range error\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught index range error"
        returnCode=4
        #ys.exit()
    except IOError:
        print("Caught file error\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught file error"
        returnCode=5
        #sys.exit()
    except OverflowError:
        print("Caught integer overflow error\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught integer overflow error"
        returnCode=6
        #sys.exit()
    except TypeError:
        print("Caught user input error\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught user input error"
        returnCode=7
        #sys.exit()
    except SystemExit:
        print("Caught no sources error\n")
        sofiaMsg="Caught no sources error"
        returnCode=8
        #sys.exit()


    if returnCode==0:
        catalogXML=ret[5].tobytes()
        pass
    else:
        catalogXML=""

    DELIMITER=chr(255)                      #"{}{}"
    msg="{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}"\
    .format( str(returnCode), DELIMITER, \
            str(element.raHeaderIndex), DELIMITER, \
            str(element.decHeaderIndex), DELIMITER, \
            str(len(ra)), DELIMITER, \
            str(len(dec)) , DELIMITER, \
            str(len(frequencies)), DELIMITER, \
            str(element.freqHeaderIndex) , DELIMITER, \
            str(catalogXML), DELIMITER, \
            str(dataPtr.nbytes)
           )
    
    return msg

def processPartition(self, partition):
    self.callPerPartitionSetup()
    for element in partition:
        yield self.doProcess(element)
```

We create a dataframe where each row of the dataframe represents a 3-dimensional array of data and containing columns of array data for the 3 position dimensions, and the array containing the pixel values (the call in doProcess for ra, dec, frequencies and pixels). The dataframe row also contains coordinate system information from the original source file, which we use to build a new set of header information, which is passed to an instantiated instance of the Partitioner class via a df.rdd.mapPartitions call.

```
p=Partitioner()
try:           
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    # Creates the positional array dataframes, 
    # and the single rows representing the 3d images in finalSubCubeDF
    # finalSubCube
    #
    ...
    ...
    ...                  
    finalSubcubeDF=finalSubcubeDF\
    .join(broadcast(raRangeDF), finalSubcubeDF.bins == raRangeDF.grp, "inner")\
    .join(broadcast(decRangeDF), finalSubcubeDF.bins == decRangeDF.grp, "inner")\
    .join(broadcast(freqRangeDF), finalSubcubeDF.bins == freqRangeDF.grp, "inner")\
    .join(broadcast(hdrDF), finalSubcubeDF.bins == hdrDF.grp, "inner")\
    .select("bins","right_ascension","declination","frequency","raHeaderIndex",\
            "decHeaderIndex","freqHeaderIndex","pixels","keys","values")

    # repartition on the bins column to distribute the processing 
    finalSubcubeDF=finalSubcubeDF.repartition("bins")
    finalSubcubeDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
    
    ...
    # Calls the partitioner class which containes the C shared object calls, as above
    ...
    
    rddout=finalSubcubeDF.rdd.mapPartitions(p.processPartition)
    DELIMITER=chr(255)
    rddout= rddout.map(lambda x:x.split(DELIMITER))
    ...
    ...
    # Write the results (which activates the computation) including the catalogue XML file
                
    rddout.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///<file path>")
except Exception as e:
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Error message captured from the calling process

```
2021-02-16 11:03:42,830 INFO ERROR! ProcessThread FAILURE...An error occurred while calling o1989.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 47.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 47.1 (TID 5875, hercules-1-2.nimbus.pawsey.org.au, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1612679558527_0181_01_000014 on host: hercules-1-2.nimbus.pawsey.org.au. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
2021-02-16 11:03:42,830 INFO ERROR! ProcessThread FAILURE...An error occurred while calling o1989.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 47.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 47.1 (TID 5875, hercules-1-2.nimbus.pawsey.org.au, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1612679558527_0181_01_000014 on host: hercules-1-2.nimbus.pawsey.org.au. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
```

And the error message from the YARN Container log

```
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Tue Feb 16 11:19:03 +0000 2021
LogLength:124
Log Contents:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 20417"...
```

So the problem is obviously memory related, but not entirely sure why that's the case given the executor and driver process memory settings are set quite high? At the moment we're just grasping at straws.

We're aware that collecting distributed data into an array under normal circumstances isn't recommended; however, it seems that being able to run multiple C shared objects in parallel across the cluster could be more efficient than running 30-40 GB extractions serially on a single machine.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts and assistance.

Comment: Well, you have a repartition, which requires a shuffle and can produce OOM. Also, have you ruled out/in the custom mapping with the C code by swapping the map for something trivial?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes, we swapped out the call to the C shared object to test, still hitting the OOM issue. The repartition was included because, given the target array sizes, the dataframe was being generated with one row for each subcube, and was only generating around eight rows and with the default parallelism of 200, we'd end up with a dataframe with mostly empty partitions.

Comment: Dealing with such large rows is new to me. I imagine the problem must lie in such an unusual data layout. Spark is designed to spill to disk when the data is too big to fit into available memory, but this design assumes large number of rows whose size is insignificant compared to the overall dataset. Here you have the opposite.

Comment: I assume Spark must require at least one row per partition! Default partition size is 128MB, so if you haven't increased it then you will have one partition per row. Rows are 15GB if I understood correctly, and executor memory is 18GB, so there is only enough memory for an executor to process one partition at a time. However, each executor has 5 cores, so could be asked to process 5 partitions in parallel.

Comment: Not sure the distribution logic is under the hood in Spark when you have less rows than total available cores, but if it assigns even two partitions to an executor there won’t be enough memory.

Comment: Perhaps reduce number executor cores to 1 so that only one row/partition is processed at any one time per executor.

Comment: Recommend Chapter 7. Optimizing and Tuning Spark Applications 

of the new edition of Learning Spark also!

Comment: Hi Chris, makes sense - we'll try reducing the cores to one per executor. I'll keep you posted. Thanks again!

Comment: Geoff, did you resolve the issue? I have similar problem with very wide row, not so wide as yours but I guess too wide for PySpark.

Comment: Hi ant0nk, not by using PySpark - we were hitting the underlying Java limitations for the maximum array sizes.  It's a valid technique if you can fit your array data within the limitations, but our requirements were for 15 - 40 GB of pixel data. We circumvented the problem by pulling the data from specific petitions using Arrow, manipulating the arrays in situ in the Python calling program, and passing the flattened array to the C program.